# How to select just an array from MongoDB using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to select just an array from MongoDB using PHP?

For example, I have data like:

```
db.articles.insert({name: "topic1", images: ["img1", "img2", "img3"]})
```

So, how I can select and print it just names of images?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: I have voted to close this question since it is vague and hard to understand what you are trying to do and what you want. Please edit your question. I have added some helpful example code but really that's all I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know so little of what you want. You are not even using valid PHP syntax.

The question is vague and doesn't make much sense.

However this should help:

```
// Make our doc
$doc = array('name' => "topic1", 'images' => array("img1", "img2", "img3"));

// insert our doc
$db->collection->insert($doc);

// Find out inserted doc
$doc = $db->collection->findOne(array('name' => 'topic1'));

// echo out a comma deliminated list of images.
echo implode(',', $doc['images']);
```